# Telethon Join Group with JSON file

Tags: json, telethon

My Python Script

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
import json
import time
import asyncio

file_json = open("data.json")

data = json.loads(file_json.read())
api_id = MY_ID
api_hash = 'MY_HASH'

u1 = TelegramClient('u1', api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    me = await u1.get_me()
    c1 = await u1.get_entity("@somechannel")
    await u1(JoinChannelRequest(c1))
with u1:
    u1.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

My Json.File

```
{
    "c1" : "@somechannel"
}
```

how to read data from json file to join channel c1

TIA sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

nvm i solve my problem

```
#IMPORTING MODULE
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import JoinChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import LeaveChannelRequest
import time
import asyncio
import json

#API ID & API HASH
api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

#JSON LOADS
file_json = open("data.json")
data = json.loads(file_json.read())

#JSON LOADS VALUE
bot = (data["bot"])
ch1 = (data["ch1"])
ch2 = (data["ch2"])
ch3 = (data["ch3"])
ch4 = (data["ch4"])
ch5 = (data["ch4"])
ch6 = (data["ch4"])
ch7 = (data["ch4"])
ch8 = (data["ch4"])
ch9 = (data["ch4"])
ch10 = (data["ch4"])

#START USER 1
u01 = TelegramClient('u01', api_id, api_hash)
async def main():
    me = await u01.get_me()
    username = me.username
    print("User Sekarang :", username)
with u01:
    u01.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```